# Express router path location

Tags: javascript, express

What is the better (most popular) location to set url path for Express routing?

1) Path inside main file:

```
// server.js
server.use('/folder', some_router);

// some_router.js
routes.all('/', (req, res) => {
   res.status(404).end();
});
```

2) Path inside router file:

```
// server.js
server.use(some_router);

// some_router.js
routes.all('/folder', (req, res) => {
   res.status(404).end();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Both of them is used, you can use the first approach for routing with a fixed sub-path like:

```
// server.js
server.use('/api', api_router);    // E.g: api/test1, api/test2, ...
```

and use from second approach for other route are on root.